# Where in Rails source is the list of built-in inflections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Oddly, I searched through what I think is all of the source code for "geese" thinking I would locate it but I didn't. Does anyone know?

Comment: Thanks for the three answers. I had looked at those files. What I was looking for (and maybe it's there and I just missed it) is the file that declares the full collection of inflections built into rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflections.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92f567ab30f240a1de152061a6eee76ca6c4da86/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflections.rb)

Comment: What I was looking for (and maybe it's there and I just missed it) is the file that declares the full collection of inflections built into rails

Comment: That's the file I linked. Those are all the built in inflections.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`ActiveSupport::Inflector`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html).

Comment: What I was looking for (and maybe it's there and I just missed it) is the file that declares the full collection of inflections built into rails

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the rails code that handles inflections, it's at https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector

If you're looking for custom pluralization in an application code, it's usually in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`

Comment: What I was looking for (and maybe it's there and I just missed it) is the file that declares the full collection of inflections built into rails